# How to hide the google maps javascript code from the page while looking through browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, client-side

Just for curious, I am asking this question. I have gone through this following website and their functionality with Google Maps inspired me.

https://batchgeo.com/map/top-100-twitter-users

So tried to have a look at their javascript code by trying to debug the site with firebug. I could not able to find their javascript where they are rendering the markers and grouping the charts. Now can anyone tell me the ways to hide the javascripts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide or secure javascript code from client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167853/how-to-hide-or-secure-javascript-code-from-client-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**No**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5167897/1671639) *you can't hide Javascript files like that*, instead they can be [Obfuscated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/194399/1671639).  Google maps in there site must have been loaded dynamically.  Here check there source tab in dev tools.

Also check this screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you missed to check the referenced script files, they are no hidden... here they're:

https://d27ixrd8sdmf11.cloudfront.net/map/json/top-100-twitter-users/1301953778