# how to acess form with external js files? how to hide sensitive content of js from client?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit-button

I'm using emailjs to send email through my free subdomain website.There are two problems with it 
1). My emailjs account-id, service-id and template-id is getting public so anybody can access it and send email through it.
2). to solve it I used following code but it steel appears in browser "inspect Element"(Developer tool).

```
     <?php echo "
<script>
   (function(){
      emailjs.init(my user id);
   })();
</script>" ; ?>
    <?php
      echo "<script src='js/formfilled.js'></script>"; 
    ?>
```

now my form submiting button is like this

```
    <button onclick="email();">
         Send
    </button>
```

now my formfill file is like this

```
var myform = $("form#myform");
function email(){

  var service_id = "default_service";
  var template_id = "xxxxxxxxx";

  myform.find("button").text("Sending...");
  emailjs.sendForm(service_id,template_id,"myform")
    .then(function(){ 
        alert("Sent!");
       myform.find("button").text("Send");
    }, function(err) {
       alert("Send email failed!\r\n Response:\n " + JSON.stringify(err));
       myform.find("button").text("Send");
    });
}
```

problem is that when I click the button rather than sending an email it reload the page .
Sorry if it is too silly i am totally beginner and Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***
it is working if i put the code in the same file(not using external js)
code:--

```
    <head>
              <script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   })(); </head>
</script>
<body>
            <!-- form is here-->
<script>

var myform = $("form#myform");
myform.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

  // Change to your service ID, or keep using the default service
  var service_id = "default_service";
  var template_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  myform.find("button").text("Sending...");
  emailjs.sendForm(service_id,template_id,"myform")
    .then(function(){ 
        alert("Sent!");
       myform.find("button").text("Send");
    }, function(err) {
       alert("Send email failed!\r\n Response:\n " + JSON.stringify(err));
       myform.find("button").text("Send");
    });
  return false;
});
</script>
</body>
```

but if i put this code in formfilled.js it is not working.
what would be the reason behind it?

Comment: [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) default type is **submit** and this may explain part of your issue

Comment: @gaetanoM thanks for your concern please see the code noww it is updated

Comment: Perfect! You added **event.preventDefault();** For the other question you may take a look to [How to hide or secure javascript code from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167853/how-to-hide-or-secure-javascript-code-from-client-side)

Comment: @gaetanoM still if I put the same code in external is file it is not working.Why?

Comment: Take a look to [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
to use

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

and loading the file before the button is loaded.