# How to put an Obfuscated code in a wordpress post?

Tags: javascript

There's a bit of code I want to encrypt from users when they use view page source or in inspect element so I want to obfuscate it. (The code is a Javascript)

The one that starts with:

> eval( function( p, a, c, k, e, d ) ...

But when I try to put that code in a single post page in the html tab, it shows nothing in the preview tab. Why is that? Or sometimes it shows the code itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide or secure javascript code from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167853/how-to-hide-or-secure-javascript-code-from-client-side)

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide or encrypt nor obfuscate js but you can use a javascript minifier.

> Minification refers to the process of removing unnecessary or redundant data without affecting how the resource is processed by the browser - e.g. code comments and formatting, removing unused code, using shorter variable and function names, and so on.

You can use https://www.minifier.org/ to minify on the go.

This minifier removes whitespace, strips comments, combines files, and optimizes/shortens a few common programming patterns.

Comment: Then why when I inpect some website I see this code that starts with  eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d)... when I deobfuscate it turn out to be a normal JS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a queck search on google and [this](https://obfuscator.io/) come out.

Make sure to look at the options and see how it should be obfuscated

Comment: This is just a fancy minifier. Who does the opposite of minifying. It's just converting to ASCII characters.

Comment: I think, it is what he needs. So with a little tweaking he could get `eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d)` That he want. the site you refer to is too simple for his need. And all minifier is more or less obfuscate  dont you think :) its just simple count on how advanced the tool is.

Comment: I agree. But at the end of the day, you can't really hide your code. It's not an intended behaviour, and it shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: Oh Why is that, its just your opinion. If i develop a tool and want people to buy should I make it simpler for them to use for free. All my hard work etc. I develop some library and I did make them with MIT License but that dose not make it the only right way. Well its as i said, its optional

Comment: Sure it's an opinion. But for protecting your intellectual property you have patent, legal defences... etc. In any case, let's not debate. this is just a comment section =D